# How do I dismiss multiple stacked SwiftUI modals/sheets simultaneously?

Tags: swiftui

I have a situation where I have a SwiftUI sheet/modal presented on top of another SwiftUI sheet/modal, and I want to dismiss them both simultaneously in the same animation. Here's a simplified example:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var modal1Presented: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        Text("I am the root view")
        Button("Present Modal 1") {
            modal1Presented = true
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $modal1Presented) {
            Modal1View(modal1Presented: $modal1Presented)
        }
    }

}

struct Modal1View: View {

    @Binding var modal1Presented: Bool
    @State var modal2Presented: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hi, I am Modal One")
        Button("Present Modal Two") {
            modal2Presented = true
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $modal2Presented) {
            Modal2View(modal1Presented: $modal1Presented, modal2Presented: $modal2Presented)
        }
    }

}

struct Modal2View: View {

    @Binding var modal1Presented: Bool
    @Binding var modal2Presented: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hi, I am Modal Two")
        Button("Dismiss Modal 2") {
            modal2Presented = false
        }
        Button("Dismiss all modals") {
            modal1Presented = false
            modal2Presented = false
        }
    }

}
```

I would have expected simply setting `modal1presented = false` would dismiss them both but that's not the case. Setting them both to `false` sequentially as above dismisses the modals sequentially, but that's not what I want either. I want them to both slide down in the same animation.

Is there a way to do what I want? If there's not, is it a temporary limitation of SwiftUI or should I not want to do this for some reason? If not why?

Comment: I think you are forcing SwiftUI to do **Unnatural** thing, I expect as user to see dismiss one by one and the apple tried to make it possible!  The level of your expectation need a custom code or a custom sheet.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's _that_ unnatural, it's a supported case in UIKit with unwind segues.

Comment: I am trying to achieve the exact same thing, dismissing multiple sheets at once, preferably with a single animation. It seems impossible without dropping down to UIKit. Did you manage to solve it @RobertAtkins?

Comment: No, never did, sorry .